# How can I load jVectorMap data using AngularJs + MVC?

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm using AngularJs & MVC in a project I'm doing to build a dashboard & need to include a jVectorMap map of the United States, which displays dynamic database data for each state.  The map displays fine when I hard code in data values, using the following code, but how would I go about retrieving these values from the database & displaying them?  When I try moving this code into my http.get.success, it doesn't work.  No map appears on my webpage:

HTML:

```
<div id="world-map-gdp" class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height:230px;"></div>
```

My app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('dashboardApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('dashboardController', DashboardController);
```

My DashboardController.js file:

```
var DashboardController = function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/Account/GetDashboardDetails')
    .success(function (result) {
        //various coding done here

    })
    .error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

var gdpData = {
    "US-PA": 1,
    "US-TN": 11,
    "US-VA": 20,
    "US-WV": 158,
    "US-NV": 85,
    "US-TX": 1,
    "US-NH": 351,
    "US-NY": 83,
    "US-HI": 1219,
    "US-VT": 366,
    "US-NM": 52,
    "US-NC": 7,
    "US-ND": 21,
    "US-NE": 105,
    "US-LA": 3,
    "US-SD": 52,
    "US-DC": 461,
    "US-DE": 13,
    "US-FL": 69,
    "US-CT": 1,
    "US-WA": 19,
    "US-KS": 16,
    "US-WI": 12,
    "US-OR": 2023,
    "US-KY": 11,
    "US-ME": 444,
    "US-OH": 867,
    "US-OK": 147,
    "US-ID": 116,
    "US-WY": 218,
    "US-UT": 1563,
    "US-IN": 17,
    "US-IL": 2,
    "US-AK": 79,
    "US-NJ": 1998,
    "US-CO": 5745,
    "US-MD": 283,
    "US-MA": 10,
    "US-AL": 12,
    "US-MO": 11,
    "US-MN": 35,
    "US-CA": 22,
    "US-IA": 59,
    "US-MI": 22,
    "US-GA": 195,
    "US-AZ": 304,
    "US-MT": 14,
    "US-MS": 12,
    "US-SC": 507,
    "US-RI": 61,
    "US-AR": 216
};

$(function () {
    $('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
        map: 'us_aea_en',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        colors: {
            "us-va": '#4E7387'
        },
        zoomOnScroll: true,
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: gdpData,
                scale: ['#E6F2F0', '#149B7E'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        },
        onRegionTipShow: function (e, el, code) {
            el.html(el.html() + ' (' + gdpData[code] + ')');
        }
    });
});
};

DashboardController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']
```

Any idea how I can retrieve this data?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: The map doesn't appear on my webpage when I place my vectormap code (beginning with "$('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({") into my "$http.get.success".  This is also true for my state values under "var gdpdata".  Ideally, this is where I would like to place it, as I could then pass values from my $http.get back into my gdpData object, but so far, doing that just prevents my map from appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by taking a different approach.  I tossed away my jVectorMap code & went with a more angular approach, using an svg map I downloaded from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_US_Map_(states_only).svg).

I then followed the tutorial I found [here](https://medium.com/@tweededbadger/tutorial-dynamic-data-driven-svg-map-with-angularjs-b112fdec421d#.8y96arv1k) on how to build an svg map with angular & it worked great!